# FreeGlut OpenGL Context Version

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, glew, freeglut

While trying to create a OpenGL 4.1 Context with Freeglut I found some inconsistencies:

I am using a AMD Graphics card with up-to-date drivers. On the AMD website it says

> OpenGL 4.2 support

When I normally run my application (consits of console window and glut-gui)(see sourcecode below), I get the following output in the console: `freeglut (C:\Users\(Username)\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Tests\OGLTest\Debug\OGLTest.exe): OpenGL >2.1 context requested but wglCreateContextAttribsARB is not available! Falling back to legacy context creation`.
I assumed my internal graphics chip is used and set my computer to use the amd card for my program. After that, the error above disappears, but another console output created by glew still says `Error: Missing GL version`.
So why is that, and can I be sure, that the opt-in to a 4.1 Context works?

Source:

```
glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
GLenum err = glewInit();
if (GLEW_OK != err) {
    std::cerr<<"Error: "<<glewGetErrorString(err)<<std::endl;
} else {
    if (GLEW_VERSION_4_1)
    {
        std::cout<<"Driver supports OpenGL 4.1\nDetails:"<<std::endl;
    }
}
glutInit(&__argc,__argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE);
glutInitContextVersion(4,1);
glutInitWindowSize(500,500);
glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
glutCreateWindow("OpenGL Test");
glutDisplayFunc(display);
glutMainLoop();
```

Comment: I am using 32 bit versions of freeglut and glew, Versions:  
glew-1.11.0;  
freeglut-2.8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it myself: Only the order of my code was wrong. The actual opt-in to a OpenGL 4 (or 4.1 in this particular case) happens after calling `glutCreateWindow("Window Title")`, surprisingly not after `glutInitContextVersion(major, minor)`. However putting the code:

```
glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
GLenum err = glewInit();
if (GLEW_OK != err) {
    std::cerr<<"Error: "<<glewGetErrorString(err)<<std::endl;
} else {
    if (GLEW_VERSION_4_1)
    {
        std::cout<<"Driver supports OpenGL 4.1\nDetails:"<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

behind `glutCreateWindow("OpenGL Test");` makes the whole thing work and creates "Driver supports OpenGL 4.1" as an Output.

Comment: This is not surprising at all, because GLEW requires a working and active OpenGL context to work. The OpenGL context however is created with calling glutCreateWindow and hence is available only after that. Frankly, if you'd have actually read the fine manual (RTFM) of FreeGLUT (or just GLUT for that matter) you'd have known that.